# How to show the derivative by using the limit definition?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$ be a probability space. For the sake of simplicity, let $\Omega$ be $\mathbb{R}$. In what follows, the measurability always refers to Borel measurability.

Let $f \colon \mathbb{R}_+ \times \Omega \to \mathbb{R}_+$ be a function such that:

**(i)** For each $z \in \Omega$, the function $k \mapsto f(k,z)$ is concave, increasing, and continuously differentiable,
while $z \mapsto f(k,z)$ is Borel measurable for each $k \in \mathbb{R}_+$;
**(ii)** $\lim_{k \downarrow 0} f'(k,z) >0$ for each $z \in \Omega$.
Here and below, $f'(k,z)$ denotes the partial derivative of $f$ with respect to $k$; and
**(iii)** $f(0,z)=0$ for all $z \in \Omega$.

Let $v \colon \mathbb{R}_+ \to \mathbb{R}_+$ be a bounded, strictly concave and strictly increasing function,
and be continuously differentiable on $(0, \infty)$.

Define a function $g $  by

\begin{align*}
g(k) := \left( \int_{\Omega} \left[ v\left( f( k, z ) \right) \right]^\alpha \mu (\mathrm{d}z) \right)^{1/\alpha},
\qquad (0<\alpha <1).
\end{align*}

> **Question:**
>   *In fact, since $g$ is concave (it has been proved), we know that the right-hand and the left-hand derivatives of $g$ exist.*
>
> **I aim to show that** $g$ is *differentiable* on $(0, \eta)$ for any fixed constant $\eta >0$, and to show the derivative of $g$ which I **conjecture** is
>   \begin{align*}
> g'(k) =  \left( \int_{\Omega} \left[ v\left( f( k, z ) \right) \right]^\alpha \mu (\mathrm{d}z) \right)^{\frac{1}{\alpha} -1 }  
> \int_{\Omega} \left[ v\left( f( k, z ) \right) \right]^{\alpha -1} 
> v'\left( f( k, z ) \right)
> f'( k, z ) \mu( \mathrm{d} z)
> \end{align*}
>   for all $0 < k < \eta$.

Here, $g'(k) = \dfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} k} g(k)$, $v'\left( f( k, z ) \right) := \dfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} f }v( f( k, z ))$,
and $f'(k, z) := \dfrac{\partial}{\partial k} f(k,z)$.

**My attempt:**

> The above stated derivative of $g$ is just *my conjecture* and I am not sure if the right-hand derivative of $g$ is equal to its left-hand derivative, thus I wish to verify it.
>   My attempt is making use of the limit definition to show the left-hand and right-hand derivatives of $g$ are the same and equal to the above stated formula.

In fact, I even got stuck in finding the left-hand side and the right-hand side derivatives of $g$. 
But I thought it might suffice to show that the left-hand side derivative $g’_-(k) := \lim_{h \to 0^-} \dfrac{g(k+h)-g(k)}{h}$ is less than the conjecture formulation that stated above, and to show that the right-hand side derivative $g’_+(k) := \lim_{h \to 0^+}\dfrac{g(k+h)-g(k)}{h}$  is greater than the conjecture formulation. Then, by concavity of $g$, we have $g’_-(k) \geq g’_+(k)$ and hence, $g’_-(k)= g’_+(k)=g’(k)$ as desired. In this connection, I think the problem becomes how to establish the relation between the right-hand derivative and conjecture formula, and relation between the left-hand derivative and conjecture formula.

Could anyone give me some guidance and help me out please?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Thank you @ArnaudMortier .

Comment: "while $z \mapsto f(k,z)$ is Borel measurable for each $k \in \mathbb{R}_+$;" that's weird: you didn't say anything about $\Omega$ being a topological space

Comment: Can't you just use the measure theory formulation of [Leibniz rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#Measure_theory_statement)? Or are you looking for its the explicit proof/derivations?

Comment: @zhw. Thanks for your comment. I’ve updated my post now.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Vlad . In fact, I’m looking for a method to solve out the derivative of the differentiable function $g$. And such $g$ is quite complicated so that I’m not sure if the conventional chain rule applies.

Comment: @Paradiesvogel But $g(k)=\left(I(k)\right)^{1/\alpha}$, where $I(k)$ is the integral which you can differentiate using formula I linked above, or am I missing something?

Comment: @Paradiesvogel I have added justification to my answer.

Comment: If all we know is that $f(k,z)$ is Borel measurable for each $k,$ why is the integral finite?

Comment: @zhw. Thanks so much for pointing out this spot, I didn’t notice that before. Please let me think about it deeply. At this moment, let’s treat the function $v$ to be bounded then. Sorry about that:) and many thanks again

Comment: " $\lim_{k \downarrow 0} f'(k,z) >0$" Why do you write this instead of  $f'(0,z)?$ Isn't $f\in C^1[0,\infty)?$

Comment: @zhw. thanks, but I think for some specific function $f(\cdot, \cdot)$, its partial derivative $f'(k,z)$ might not be well defined at $k=0$, (for example, $f(k,z) = zk^\alpha$ with $\alpha \in (0,1)$, then $f'(k,z) = \alpha z k^{\alpha -1}$ is not well defined at $k=0$). Besides, $f \in C^1(0, \infty)$. Thanks again:)

Answer (score 3):

To use the Liebnitz rule, nicely explained by Vlad, we need

$$\tag 1 \int_\Omega \partial_k (v^\alpha \circ f(k,z))\,d \mu (z) <\infty.$$

Think about this for a bit: If we had $\Omega, f, v,$ such that the integrand is not bounded for some $k,$ we could fashion a probability measure $\mu$ on $\Omega$ for which $(1)$ fails. So boundedness is something we need to look for.

Let $\mathcal U$ be the collection of functions $u\in C^1(0,\infty)$ that are positive, increasing, and concave. Let $\mathcal U_b$ be the set of bounded functions $u\in \mathcal U.$

Lemma: Suppose $u\in \mathcal U.$  Then

$$u'(x) \le \frac{u(x)}{x}\,\,\text {for all } x>0.$$

If in addition $u\in \mathcal U_b,$ then

$$u'(x)x \le \|u\|_\infty.$$

I'll leave the proof of this to you for now. It's fairly simple, but ask questions if you like.

Let's turn to $(1).$ We are given $v\in \mathcal U_b.$ This implies $v^\alpha \in \mathcal U_b.$ Thus by the lemma, we have

$$ (v^\alpha)'(x) x \le  \|v^\alpha\|_\infty.$$

We also have $f(k,z) \in \mathcal U$ as a function of $k$ for each fixed $z.$ Thus the lemma gives

$$f'(k,z) \le \frac{f(k,z)}{k}.$$

It follows that

$$\tag 2(v^\alpha)'(f(k,z)) f'(k,z) \le (v^\alpha)'(f(k,z)) \frac{f(k,z)}{k} \le \frac{\|v^\alpha\|_\infty}{k}.$$

But the left side of $(2)$ is exactly the integrand in $(1)$. Thus for $k \ge k_0$ we have the uniform bound $\|v^\alpha\|_\infty/k_0$ on the integrands. Of course the constant function equal to to this bound belongs to $L^1(\mu),$ since we're in a probablity space. This allows us to use Leibnitz on each interval $(k_0,\infty),$ and gives the desired result.

Comment: What do you mean by "this needs to hold for [...] every probability space $(\Omega,\mu)$"? Aren't $(\Omega,\mu)$ fixed once and for all? The definition of the map $f$ requires it to be fixed, doesn't it?

Comment: Thanks @zhw. In fact, by concavity of the function $[ v ( f ( \cdot , z))]^\alpha$ for each $z$, we can directly have that for any $k>0$,  $ (v^\alpha)’ (f(k,z)) f’(k,z) \leq (v^\alpha)’ ( f( k_0,z)) f’(k_0,z)=: M(z)$ for each $z$ whenever $k_0 \in (0, k)$. Evidently, $M(z)$ is bounded and thus $\mu$-integrable. I think the difficulty is how to show that $g$ is differentiable, otherwise we cannot directly apply the Chain rule and Leibniz rule.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier  I should have said "probability measure". Notice if there existed $\Omega, f, v$ such that the slice integrand is unbounded, you can cook up a $\mu$ that yields nonintegrability. That would be a counterexample.

Comment: @Paradiesvogel No, my answer shows $g$ is differentiable by Leibniz.

Comment: @zhw. Would you mind to explain more details about how the differentiability of $g$ is proven via Leibniz rule please? I thought the role of Leibniz rule just gives us the interchange between the differential operator and integral operator. Perhaps I am missing something out. Many thanks again:)

Comment: @Paradiesvogel See Vlad's answer. It's also here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#Measure_theory_statement

Comment: Thanks so much for your kind reply, @zhw. In fact, I had been reading the measure-theoretic Leibniz rule carefully. As you and Vlad mentioned, applying this Leibniz rule yields that $ \dfrac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} k} g(k)= \left( \int_{\Omega} \left[ v\left( f( k, z ) \right) \right]^\alpha \mu (\mathrm{d}z) \right)^{\frac{1}{\alpha} -1 }  
\int_{\Omega} \left[ v\left( f( k, z ) \right) \right]^{\alpha -1} 
v'\left( f( k, z ) \right)
f'( k, z ) \mu( \mathrm{d} z)$ for each $k>0$, which is the analogously stated result of Leibniz theorem.

Comment: @zhw. But from my own opinion, I am still confused that does Leibniz theorem tell us $g(\cdot)$ is differentiable on $(0, \infty)$? In other words, does the aforementioned equality imply the differentiability of $g$ on $(0, \infty)$? Your kind help is much appreciated! :)

Comment: @Paradiesvogel  Yes it does say that. Leibniz says that if

$$H(k) = \int_\Omega h(k,z)\,d\mu(z),$$

and certain hypotheses hold, then $H$ is differentiable for all $k$ and $H'(k) = \int_\Omega \partial h(k,z)/\partial k\,d\mu(z).$

Comment: @zhw. Thank you very much for your kind help. It's a huge help to me! I learned it. :)

Comment: @Paradiesvogel You are welcome.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier The awarding of the bounty for this problem is disappointing. Vlad didn't solve the problem; I did. Vlad's answer is fine for what it does, but it doesn't address the hard part of the problem: Why is Leibniz applicable here? I.e., why are those integrands in $L^1(\mu)?$ This is the crux of the matter. I took on that part, and solved it.

Comment: @zhw. Thank you for covering the part I (unintentionally) slacked on in my answer! Your meticulousness and clarity of explanation definitely deserve +1 and more!

Comment: @zhw. The outcome is disappointing indeed, I wish I could have split the bounty between you two. Part of the reason I set up this bounty was because I had no time to try and tackle this question myself and I wanted to learn something. In the end neither answer was completely crystal clear to me and after reading them I still felt that I would need time to clarify things (I did try to ask questions along the way, maybe not the right questions), so the upvotes determined the winner.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier No worries, I got it covered (=

Comment: @Vlad Wow that's really fair play!

Comment: @ArnaudMortier Ah, I didn't realize you let the bounty lapse so that the up votes determined the bounty. Thank you for your comment. And ask further questions on the problem if you like.

Comment: @Vlad I second Arnaud's comment on fair play. That was a splendid gesture and I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps I am missing something out, but it seems to me that you can obtain your final result using [Leibniz's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) as shown below.

$$
\begin{align*}
g(k) := \left( \int_{\Omega} \big[ v\left( f( k, z ) \right) \big]^\alpha \mu (\mathrm{d}z) \right)^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}
=I^\frac{1}{\alpha}\left(k\right)\qquad (0<\alpha <1).
\end{align*}
$$
where 
$$
I(k)=\int_{\Omega} v^\alpha \left( f( k, z ) \right) \mu (\mathrm{d}z)
$$

Thus, if we apply regular chain rule we get

$$
\frac{\partial }{\partial k}\left[g\left(k\right)\right] =\frac{\partial }{\partial k}\left[I^\frac{1}{\alpha}\left(k\right)\right]
=\frac{1}{\alpha}I^{\frac{1}{\alpha}-1}\left(k\right) \frac{\partial }{\partial k}\left[I \left(k\right)\right]
$$

Then,  using [Measure theory form of Leibniz rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#Measure_theory_statement) we write

$$
 \frac{\partial }{\partial k}\left[I \left(k\right)\right] =
 \frac{\partial }{\partial k}\left[\int_{\Omega} \big[ v\left( f( k, z ) \right) \big]^\alpha \mu \left(\mathrm{d}z\right)\right] =
\int_{\Omega} \frac{\partial }{\partial k}\big[ v\left( f( k, z ) \right) \big]^\alpha \mu\left(\mathrm{d}z\right) =
\int_{\Omega} \alpha v^{\alpha-1}\left( f( k, z ) \right) v'\left( f( k, z )\right) \frac{\partial }{\partial k}\big[  f( k, z )  \big] \mu (\mathrm{d}z) =
\alpha\int_{\Omega}  v^{\alpha-1}\left( f \right) v'\left( f \right) f_k\left( k, z \right)   \mu \left(\mathrm{d}z\right)
$$

Substituting the last expression into previous formula for $g'(k)$ we get

$$
g'\left(k\right) = \frac{1}{\alpha} \left(\int_\Omega \nu^\alpha\left(f\right)\mu\left(\mathrm{d}z\right)\right)^{\frac{1}{\alpha}-1} 
\cdot
\alpha\int_{\Omega}  v^{\alpha-1}\left( f \right) v'\left( f \right) f_k\left( k, z \right)   \mu \left(\mathrm{d}z\right)
$$
$$
\boxed{g'\left(k\right) =  \left(\int_\Omega \nu^\alpha\left(f\right)\mu\left(\mathrm{d}z\right)\right)^{\frac{1}{\alpha}-1} 
\int_{\Omega}  v^{\alpha-1}\left( f \right) v'\left( f \right) f_k\left( k, z \right)   \mu \left(\mathrm{d}z\right)}
$$

where $f=f\left(k,z\right)$ and $f_k\left(k,z\right)=\dfrac{\partial f\left(k,z\right)}{\partial k}$.

---

#### Justification for Using Leibniz's rule

As pointed out in comments by the OP, I have not provided justification for using Leibniz's rule in measure-theoretical form:

> Let  $X$ is an open subset of $  \mathbb{R} $, and $\Omega$  is a measure space. 
>   Suppose $ F\colon X\times \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb {R}$ satisfies the following conditions:
>
> - $ F(x,\omega )$ is a Lebesgue-integrable function of $\omega$  for each $ x\in X$.
> - For almost all $\omega \in \Omega$, the derivative $ F_{x} $ exists for all $ x\in X$.
> - There is an integrable function $\displaystyle \theta \colon \Omega \rightarrow \mathbf {R}$ such that $$\left\lvert F_{x}(x,\omega )\right\rvert\leq \theta (\omega )$$  for all $ x\in X$ and almost every $\omega \in \Omega $.
>
> Then, for all $x\in X$,
>   $$
> {\frac {d}{dx}}\int _{\Omega }F(x,\omega )\,d\omega =\int _{\Omega }F_{x}(x,\omega )\,d\omega .
> $$

Let us verify the last condition for the integrand

$$
F\left(k,z\right)=\left[ v\big( f( k, z ) \big) \right]^\alpha , \qquad 0<\alpha<1.
$$

Observe that $F\left(k,z\right)$ is superposition of three concave increasing functions (treating $k\mapsto f\left(k,z\right)$ as function of single variable $k$)

$$
F\left(\cdot\right) = F_1\circ F_2\circ F_3 = F_3\left(F_2\left(F_1\left(\cdot\right)\right)\right),
$$

where

$$
\begin{aligned}
F_1\left(\tau\right) &= f\left(\tau,z\right), &&\text{where $z$ is fixed} \\
F_2\left(\tau\right) &= v\left(\tau\right), &&\\
F_3\left(\tau\right) &= \tau^{\alpha}, && 0<\alpha<1
\end{aligned}
$$

with $\tau$ being dummy variable.
As an exercise, I propose you to try to show explicitly that superposition of $F\left(\cdot\right) = F_1\circ F_2\circ F_3 =  v^\alpha\left( f\left( k, z \right) \right)$ is convex in $k$.

Recall that concave function of single variable has [*monotonically decreasing derivative*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concave_function#Functions_of_a_single_variable), which means that $F'\left(\tau\right)\leq F'\left(\tau_0\right)$ whenever $\tau\leq\tau_0$.
For example, we can get bound

$$
\begin{aligned}
F'\left(\tau\right)&<F'\left(0\right)& \text{since}& &f \colon \mathbb{R}_+ \times \Omega \to \mathbb{R}_+ \implies \tau>0
\end{aligned}
$$

where $F'\left(0\right)$ does not depend on $\tau$ (and possibly depends on $\omega$).

Thus, choosing nonnegative constant $k_0$ we can bound derivative as
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial k} \Big[v^\alpha\big( f\left( k, z \right) \big)\Big] \leq \left.\frac{\partial}{\partial k} \Big[v^\alpha\big( f\left( k, z \right) \big)\Big]\right\rvert_{k_0} 
\qquad\text{ whenever }   k\geq k_0. 
$$

Thus the third condition is satisfied.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Vlad . It seems to be working fine now. When I asked you in previous comment, my brain was dead and I thought the bound derivative might not be integrable. Please give me more time to think about it more carefully. Your kind help is much appreciated! :)

Comment: But why is $\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial k} \Big[v^\alpha\big( f\left( k, z \right) \big)\Big]\right\rvert_{k_0}$  in $L^1(\mu)?$

Comment: @zhw. My reasoning goes as following:

**I**. Since $f\left(k,z\right)$ is measurable in $z$ and concave, increasing, and continuously differentiable in $k$, the derivative $\partial_x f\left(k,z\right)$ exists, is continuous, and monotone decreasing. 

**II**. Since [composition of measurable and continuous functions is measurable](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1169122/229317), the derivative $\partial_k\left[v^\alpha\big( f\left( k, z \right) \big)\right]$   Lebesgue–integrable for any finite number $k_0\in\mathbb{R}^+$.

Comment: @Vlad  I don't understand why you say $\int_\Omega \partial_k v^\alpha(f(k,z)) \,d\mu(z)<\infty.$ Have I missed something? I would think the boundedness of $v$ has to play a role, but I didn't see you use it.

Comment: WHen you conclude "the third condition is satisfied", isn't there an absolute value missing? How do you justify that $|\partial_k\ldots|$ is bounded?

Comment: @ArnaudMortier You don't need absolute values because those functions increase with $k$, hence the derivatives are nonnegative

Comment: @zhw. Thanks for your answer. But then shouldn't we be trying to bound them below rather than above?