# Question: Let $f$ is continuous, $g$ is measurable function.Show that composition function $f\circ g$ is measurable

Tags: measurable-functions

How to show that composition of $f$ and $g$ is measurable?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1169122/composition-of-measurable-continuous-functions-is-it-measurable

Comment: Not everybody uses the term 'measurable' for 'Lebesgue measurable'. Some people use it for Borel measurability.

Comment: Thank you sir for the suggestion..but is there any way to solve my question?