# Convergence and measurability

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

I was doing an assignment for my sophomore year course of Measure and Integration, and I encountered this problem.

Show that following series is convergent $\forall a\in \mathbb{R}$
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{a^k}{k!(k+3)}$$
hence show that if the function $f: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is a measurable function, then following function is so $$g(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(f(x)\right)^k}{k!(k+3)}$$

I have no idea how to prove the second part. In the first part, I have shown that the series is bounded by $e^a$. How do I conclude convergence from that? And please help with the second part.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use that pointwise limits of measurable functions are measurable. Can you show that the partial sums are measurable functions?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea about the second part :(

Comment: Try using the ideas in these posts https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/541118/proving-that-sum-of-two-measurable-functions-is-measurable\\ https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1169122/composition-of-measurable-continuous-functions-is-it-measurable.  In the second one, your continuous function will be $x^k$